# How to add volatility constraint to this optimization problem using pyportfolioopt library?

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio

I would like to know how to add a volatility constraint to this optimization problem. I would like to restrict the portfolio to a maximum of 2% volatility.

What I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinances as yf
from pypfopt import risk_models
from pypfopt import expected_returns
from pypfopt import EfficientFrontier
from pypfopt import objective_functions

....
tickers = [ "BLK", "BAC", "AAPL", "TM", "WMT",
       "JD", "INTU", "MA", "UL", "CVS",
       "DIS", "AMD", "NVDA", "PBI", "TGT"]

df = yf.download(tickers)

data = df.copy()

data = data.dropna()

data.columns = data.columns.droplevel()

data = data["Close"]
data.columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
               "11", "12",
               "13", "14", "15"]

mu = expected_returns.mean_historical_return(data)
Sigma = risk_models.sample_cov(data)

ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, Sigma)

ef.add_constraint(lambda x : x[0] == 0.02) #THIS DOESNT WORK

w = ef.max_sharpe()

cleaned_weights = ef.clean_weights()

ef.portfolio_performance(verbose=True)
```

Result:

Expected annual return: 44.2%
Annual volatility: **36.2%**
Sharpe Ratio: 1.17

How could I add the volatility constraint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to optimize a portfolio of all stocks to just 2% without adding cash asset. So either add cash (or any other low-risk asset) to the ticker list, or rethink your maximum volatility constraint. I couldn't find a direct way of optimizing a portfolio and setting a maximum volatility constraint. But I put together the following code which derives the portfolio you are looking for indirectly.

The code computes the efficient frontier of portfolios over a specified range of portfolio volatility levels that can't be greater than your 2% volatility constraint. To make this work, you'll either have to add a cash asset (like ticker: BIL), or you need to increase your maximum volatility constraint up to something like 30% if you're sticking with 100% stock portfolio.

In the code below, I added ticker: BIL (SPDR Bloomberg 1-3 Month T-Bill ETF) to the ticker list, to represent a cash asset. Also the code:

1. Computes the minimum risk portfolio and uses its portfolio volatility value as the minimum possible portfolio volatility that a portfolio can have given the inputs.
2. Computes 100 efficient frontier portfolios over a given range of possible portfolio volatility levels. Here you can define the maximum portfolio volatility you are willing to accept.

```
max_volatility = 0.02 # <---- Set this to whatever maximum volatility you want
```

3. Finally, the code finds the highest sharpe ratio portfolio out of the 100 efficient frontier portfolios it computed and returns the weights, expected return, volatility, and a plot of the efficient frontier with a red dot showing the maximum sharpe portfolio given your constraint.

4. Added one last plot to show the portfolio's cumulative return over time.

Here is the full code.

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pypfopt import risk_models, expected_returns, efficient_frontier
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define the list of tickers for which we want to optimize the portfolio
tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'BIL', 'XOM', 'MSFT']

# Download historical data for the tickers
data = yf.download(tickers, period='max')['Adj Close']
data = data[tickers] # Needed because yf.download changes the order of the tickers list

# Calculate expected returns and covariance matrix of daily returns
returns = np.log(data / data.shift(1)).dropna()
mu = expected_returns.mean_historical_return(data)
cov_matrix = risk_models.sample_cov(data)

# Get the minimum risk portfolio volatility
ef = efficient_frontier.EfficientFrontier(mu, cov_matrix)
ef.min_volatility()

# Define the range of portfolio volatilities to consider
min_volatility = ef.portfolio_performance(risk_free_rate=risk_free_rate)[1]
max_volatility = 0.02 # <---- Set this to whatever maximum volatility you want
num_portfolios = 100

# Define the objective function for the optimization problem
def objective(weights, mu, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    portfolio_return = np.sum(mu * weights)
    portfolio_volatility = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights)))
    sharpe_ratio = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_volatility
    return -sharpe_ratio

# Set up the constraints for the optimization problem
constraints = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1}]

# Define the bounds for the weights
bounds = tuple((0, 1) for _ in range(len(tickers)))

# Calculate the efficient frontier
frontier_volatilities = np.linspace(min_volatility, max_volatility, num_portfolios)
frontier_returns = []
frontier_weights = []

for volatility in tqdm(frontier_volatilities):
    # Set up the constraint for maximum volatility
    constraints += ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sqrt(np.dot(x.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, x))) - volatility},)
    
    # Solve the optimization problem
    result = minimize(objective, len(tickers)*[1./len(tickers)], args=(mu, cov_matrix, 0.02), method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
    
    # Store the results
    frontier_returns.append((result.x * mu).sum())
    frontier_weights.append(result.x)
    
    # Remove the maximum volatility constraint
    constraints = constraints[:-1]

# Convert the weights of each portfolio to a DataFrame
frontier_weights = pd.DataFrame(frontier_weights, columns=tickers)

# Print the portfolio with the highest Sharpe ratio
max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(frontier_returns)
max_sharpe_portfolio = frontier_weights.iloc[max_sharpe_idx, :]
max_sharpe_volatility = frontier_volatilities[max_sharpe_idx]
max_sharpe_return = frontier_returns[max_sharpe_idx]
max_sharpe_ratio = max_sharpe_return / max_sharpe_volatility

print("Portfolio with the highest Sharpe ratio:")
print(round(max_sharpe_portfolio, 4))
print('\n')
print(f"Expected return: {max_sharpe_return:.4f}")
print(f"Volatility: {max_sharpe_volatility:.4f}")
print(f"Sharpe ratio: {max_sharpe_ratio:.4f}")

# Plot the efficient frontier
plt.plot(frontier_volatilities, frontier_returns)
plt.plot(max_sharpe_volatility, max_sharpe_return, 'ro', label='Max Sharpe Ratio')
plt.xlabel('Volatility')
plt.ylabel('Expected return')
plt.title('Efficient Frontier')
plt.legend()
plt.show();

# Plot the cumulative returns of the portfolio
plt.plot(returns.index, portfolio_cumulative_returns)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Cumulative returns")
plt.title("Cumulative returns of portfolio")
plt.show();
```